# Move e-mail to custom mailbox 'done' with keyboard

Tags: email, keyboard-shortcuts

My use case is this:

I'm a 'zero-inbox' person. Any Mail that I want to keep, I manually move to my 'done' Mailbox. I'm trying to find a way to do this automatically.

I know that there is a commercial solution called Mail Act-On, but the price made me balk.

I also saw that there's a 'Move to archive' option but that doesn't interest me.

I was hoping I could use System Preferences/Keyboard/Shortcuts but I don't seem to get the syntax right.

[image]

I tried

```
Move to "done"
Move to done
Move to... done
```

but was unsuccessful. Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer - put the desired Mailbox into 'Favorites' (by drag and dropping onto the bar) and then there are direct shortcuts that appear (ctrl-command-)